# How to change the filename of direct fopen output?

Tags: php, csv

I am using this script to show a csv file:

```
if (isset($_GET['csv'])) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ($dataArray as $k => $v) {
        fputcsv($out, $v);
    }
    fclose($out);
    exit();
}
```

And this Javascript to open the csv for a direct download:

```
<a href="#" class="export" onclick="window.open(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + \'&csv=1\');">
```

Now I want to change the filename to something like:

```
subscriptions_2014_10_23.csv
```

Someone knows how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another header specifying the file name. Then throw in some date function to add into that:

```
$filename = 'subscriptions_' . date('Y_m_d') . '.csv';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `header`

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=subscriptions_2014_10_23.csv');`

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should use header for file name :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; subscriptions_2014_10_23.csv"');
```